# Unknown return value in CNTK 103A

Tags: python, dataset, image-classification, mnist

I came across this statement from [CNTK 103A](https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/CNTK_103A_MNIST_DataLoader.html):

```
gzfname, h = urlretrieve(src, './delete.me')
```

I understand all the rest but that `gzfname, h = ......`

What exactly is the purpose of `h`, is it a filehead thing?

#### Code:

```
def load_or_download_mnist_files(filename, num_samples, local_data_dir):
    gzfname, h = urlretrieve(src, './delete.me')
    if (local_data_dir):
        local_path = os.path.join(local_data_dir, filename)
    else:
        local_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename)

    if os.path.exists(local_path):
        gzfname = local_path
    else:
        local_data_dir = os.path.dirname(local_path)
        if not os.path.exists(local_data_dir):
            os.makedirs(local_data_dir)
        filename = "http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/" + filename
        print ("Downloading from" + filename, end=" ")
        gzfname, h = urlretrieve(filename, local_path)
        print ("[Done]")

    return gzfname
```

Answer (score 1):

`gzfname, h` is doing tuple unpacking from the return of `urlretrieve`.  From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve), `urlretrieve` returns:

> Return a tuple (filename, headers) where filename is the local file name under which the object can be found, and headers is whatever the info() method of the object returned by urlopen() returned (for a remote object). Exceptions are the same as for urlopen().

And the `info()` method of the [`urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) object returns:

> `info()` — return the meta-information of the page, such as headers, in the form of an email.message_from_string() instance (see Quick Reference to HTTP Headers)

So, `h` is meta information about the retrieved page.

Comment: so if h is of no use (and could not find any subsequent use in the code), then I can also do without it by using gz = urlretrieve.....?

Comment: You can not ignore the `h` completely.  You must either use `gzfname = urlretrieve(...)[0]` to select the first element of the tuple, or `gzfname, _ = urlretrieve(...)`  can be used by convention to set the value into `_` which is the convention for assigning to a name you want to ignore.